# Call an activity Alert Box from Broadcast Receiver android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app which launches a Broadcast. I want to display a popup no matter on which activity i am if the app is running and if not then push a notification

Here is my code

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context ctx, Intent intent) 
     {
         if (isRunning(ctx))
         {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent (ctx, NotifyTagabilityCounter.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ctx.startActivity(myIntent);
         }
         else
         {
             mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                      ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

             Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Game.class);
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             i.putExtra(Constants.TAG_TIMESTAMP, true);
             PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                  i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);      

             NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                  new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher)

             Notification notification = mBuilder.getNotification();
             notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

             mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
             mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

             SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
                     "UserSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.TAG_NOTIFICATION, true);
            editor.commit();
         }
     }

     public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) 
     {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)  ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks =  activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) 
            {
                if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                         task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
                    return true;                                  
            }

            return false;
        }
```

On creating new Activity `NotificyTagabilityCounter`

```
ublic class NotifyTagabilityCounter extends Activity
{
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_RECEIVED = 0x1221;
    static final String ACTION = "com.trib.broadcast";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceivedReceiver, filter);
    }

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceivedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (ACTION.equals(action)) 
            {
                displayAlert();
            }
        }
    };
```

All I get is a black screen. I want my last activity to be shown and on top of it a popup AlertDisplay is shown. How can this be done..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To done that:
1- define two `BroadcastReceivers` the 1st one in the manifest with low priority and the 2nd one in each activity in your app (run time) with a higher priority.
The 1st `BroadcastReceivers` should show a notification
and the 2nd broadcast should `abort()` the broadcast and display the dialog.

2- send an ordered broadcast.

PS: you can create a BaseActivtiy witch extends Activity, and define the 2nd broadcast on it (dont foget to register and unregister the broadcast in `onStart()` and `onStop()`),
then make all your Activity`s extends the BaseActivtiy

Comment: I did the same but Do i have to define the popup and server call in base activity? How can I call them properly, can you make an example? From my broadcast receiver I am sending a broadcast to the BaseActivty broadcast but it gets error while creating popup as token null